# HTML size unit for responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've been basing my font-sizes and widths and whatnot on ems ever since I did my first serious website project about 5 years ago and I'm very good with it. I've read about rem and that would be exactly for me if it wasn't for IE's lacking or only partial support for it.

What I'm asking is what is de facto unit for responsive web design nowadays and how does em compete against it?

UPDATE: so there are no really a de facto unit(s), though em, rem, vh,vw and % all  are good to use for responsive web design. Use the unit(s) you're comfortable with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no de facto in web development.
For widths,heights, padding, margin etc... I use `%` or sometimes viewport relative units(`vh`,`vw`) for experimentation because of browser support. For stuff related with fonts like font-size I use `em` or `rem`, for `line-height` I use unit-less approach. But you are also good with pixels. Relative units(`%,vw,vh,em,rem` etc...) scale better in this era of mobile, tablet, phablet devices. Use whatever you are comfortable with.

Comment: @user2288056 That's good,prepare yourself for the future. `vw` and `vh` are added to the spec exactly because of responsive web design.

Comment: As I see my question is too abstractive for stackoverflow. Can anyone point me to another source when I need ananswer to these kind of questions?

Answer (score 1):

viewport units are used nowadays for responsive website as it measures using media viewport resolution size. They are: vw, vh, vmin, vmax.

```
1vw = 1% of viewport width
1vh = 1% of viewport height
1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller
1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger
```

See below image how the font size is responsive in different sizes:

[image]

[source](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

But be careful while using it: [see can i use viewport units?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Comment: But rem is not for responsiveness like viewport units does.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I can already do that (animation) with em